# How to make this switch case dynamic

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, switch-statement

So I'm trying to make this switch case dynamic, instead of hard coding the entries as the requested fields are not always the same. However, the variable I created doesn't work and I can't think of way of changing it. how could I modify the variable `id`  so that it does the same as calling 'items.city'?

```
function formatData(response, requestedFields){
  
 return response.map(function(items) {
    var row = [];
   console.log(requestedFields.asArray())
    requestedFields.asArray().forEach(function (field) { 
      var id = items.field;
      switch (field.getId()) {
        case 'submittedAt':
          return row.push(dateTime(items.submittedAt));
        case field:
          return row.push(id);
        default:
          return row.push('');
     
        // case 'city':
        //   return row.push(items.city);
        // case 'country':
        //   return row.push(items.country);

        
      }
    });
    return { values: row };
  });

}
```

Comment: Is your problem what value is assigned to the variable `id`? or that the `case field:` section never runs?

Comment: @PhinJensen both I've tried manually putting `row.push(items.field)` didn't work also I console logged after `case field:` never got there.

Comment: What kind of object is `field`? It looks like you're treating it as a string in the switch statement (because that's what the first `case` option is), but it also seems to have an instance method on it (`field.getId()`), so I'm a little bit confused about that.

Part of your problem may be that `items.field` is trying to access a key named "field" on the items object, *not* a key with whatever value is stored in the variable `field`. To do that, you want to use bracket notation: `items[field]`.

Comment: So this is google app script and I been following the docs on how to build a connector for google data studio. However once I build the fields it returns an empty object, however, somehow it still works if I hard code the case statement and I can also call `field.getId()` and it gives me the id of the object, what I believe is in there is something like "{ id: 'company', name: 'company', type : TEXT }" because that's how I built the fields. 
So to get the id it would be something like items`[field.id]` could I do this `items[field.getId()]` ?